# Retrieving outlook.com/live.com data using Office 365 unified API

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

I would like to retrieve calendar information from my live.com/outlook.com account using the new Office 365 unified API (preview) instead of the old Live SDK. Is this or will this be possible ?

If I use the Graph Explorer (https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/) and try to sign in with my live account I get the following error:

Correlation ID: 1d81d884-b2e8-4413-a5da-f1c38268a346 
Timestamp: 2015-05-04 17:07:16Z 
AADSTS50020: User account 'myaccount@live.nl' from external identity provider 'live.com' is not supported for application '8a3eb86b-8149-4231-9ff3-3c50958ea0fd'. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant. Please sign out and sign in again with an Azure Active Directory user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. We are working towards bringing the Outlook.com accounts into the fold for the REST APIs, so stay tuned!

UPDATE: We have announced [phased enabling of the REST APIs for Outlook.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/08/12/unified-outlook-apis-for-office-365-amp-outlook-com-are-here.aspx). Mailboxes that are not yet enabled will get a specific error message (either `MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI` or `MailboxNotSupportedForRESTAPI`.

Comment: Great thanx! that will be the outlook.com, live.com and hotmail.com accounts then ?

Comment: Should be, as long as they get their email and such via Outlook.com.

Comment: Hello @JasonJohnston, any news on that? Thanks!